# Get "client info is null" with MSAL 1.1.0-preview

Tags: azure-ad-msal

I have some code that was working on MSAL 1.1.0-alpha307, but on 1.1.0-preview it throws exception "client info is null", which is returned in the HTTP response. The app is registered in the AAD V2 endpoint and it gets MS Graph data. From the stack trace below, it looks like its able to get the token for Graph but not able to cache it.

**Can anyone suggest a diagnosis/fix/workaround?**

This is the code:

```
var bootstrapContext = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First().BootstrapContext as BootstrapContext;
UserAssertion userAssertion = new UserAssertion(bootstrapContext.Token);
ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Password"]);
ConfidentialClientApplication cca =
                    new ConfidentialClientApplication(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientID"],
                                                      "https://localhost:44355", clientCred, null, null);
string[] graphScopes = { "Files.Read.All" };
AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOfAsync(graphScopes, userAssertion, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0");
```

This is the stack trace:

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"client info is null","ExceptionType":"Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalClientException","StackTrace":"   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.ClientInfo.CreateFromJson(String clientInfo)\r\n   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.SaveTokenResponseToCache()\r\n   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.PostTokenRequest()\r\n   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.<RunAsync>d__33.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.ConfidentialClientApplication.<AcquireTokenOnBehalfCommonAsync>d__16.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.ConfidentialClientApplication.<AcquireTokenOnBehalfOfAsync>d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at Office_Add_in_ASPNET_SSO_WebAPI.Controllers.ValuesController.<Get>d__0.MoveNext() in D:\\repos\\Office-Add-in-ASP.NET-SSO\\Complete\\Office-Add-in-ASPNET-SSO-WebAPI\\Controllers\\ValuesController.cs:line 46\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"}
```

Comment: Same issue here, works in the start but later on at refreshing the token this exception appears. Dit you find a fix as you asked this on 17 may.

Comment: This is supposed to be fixed. I've made an enquiry with the developers. I'll report back what I find out.

Comment: Our developers ask that you install the http://www.telerik.com/fiddler tool. Capture the Request/Response from when this happens. You can't add that to a comment, so please start a new question and include the Fiddler data in it.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a bug in Azure Active Directory V2.0 endpoint. It is fixed.